# Entity with multiple one-to-many relations of the same type and GreenDAO

Tags: android, database, orm, one-to-many, greendao

The entities generate by GreenDAO must be something like this:

```
class A {    
    public List<B> bList1;
    public List<B> bList2;    
}

class B{
    ...
}
```

I know how it works with on list of a given type.

The problem is that I'm  not sure if the generated code can know if a B object is of bList1 or bList2.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can: You can give a name to each relationship. In B class, you will have something like that:

```
class B {
  A aRelation1;
  A aRelation2;
}
```